# Setting CSS float to right cause empty space

Tags: css, css-float

I have problem with aligning buttons and texts to right using float: right; command. But after doing this the empty space appears in the right of page. I've try overflow: hidden; and it fixed the empty space but also it disable drop menus.

CSS code:

```
/* Menu CSS */#cssmenu,
#cssmenu > ul {
  background: url(images/highlight-bg.png) repeat;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu:before,
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:before,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: auto;
  zoom: 1;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  background: url(images/menu-bg.png) repeat;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="cssmenu">
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><span>خانه</span></a></li>
    <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>⌄ حرفه ما</span></a>
      <ul>
        <li class="last"><a href="#"><span>فعالیت های ما</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>⌄ مدیا</span></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><span>اخبار</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>نشر</span></a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="#"><span>دانلود</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="last"><a href="#"><span>تماس با ما</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make a jsfiddle link with the issue.

Comment: Please try and provide only the relevant code. Reduce the css to a minimal problem. Regarding the second question, open a second question. Only one problem should be asked and answered att a time.

Comment: also add the relevant html code.

Comment: Do you have your html dir set to rtl ?

Comment: speaking of menu, there is no `hover` used in your CSS....please provide jsFiddle and follow what d-Pixie suggested please!